# connection string for xml datasource

Tags: .net, xml, connection-string

I have data in xml file (it is equivalent to a few tables in relational database, but I need to use that xml), and I want to use entity framework in application which should edit that data. I need connection string which points to that xml file, to pass it to EF, but I can not find such an example on Internet.
So, is that even possible, and what should look like connection string which points to xml file ? I'd prefer to access file via file system, since it should be shipped with application and accessible locally.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that, but you might consider using DOM methods and System.XmlDocument.  With a couple methods (load, save, selectNodes, createElement), you'd likely have what you need.  Interested in a EF approach if there is one though.

Comment: Infact I have already implemented loading from xml file to DataSet, and then to EF DbSet. Maybe it wouldn't be a problem to also implement other operations by hand, but it's just not nice solution, if there is much more elegant solution to leave all work to framework. Since DataSet loads xml perfectly, I am pretty sure it should not be problem for EF to do same using proper connection string, so I really hope I can find such solution.

Comment: What database are you using?  You should be able to load database directly without using EF.

Comment: It's a small project and I do not use database. There's just xml file.